# 何処ですか vs 何処に有りますか

Tags: grammar

Recently I learned the structure A: "something が何処に有りますか。"

But I have previously learned the structure B: "something は何処ですか。"

My understanding is that these 2 structures are identical in meaning.

My feeling is that structure B is more casual and hence less formal than structure A.

Is my understanding and feeling correct ?

Is there any nuanced difference between these 2 structures or are they completely interchangable ?

All insights welcome.

Comment: Do you mean 〜はどこにありますか, rather than 〜が? By the way, I would write both どこ and ある (or いる) in hiragana.

Comment: @aguijonazo My textbook says to use が for this structure. 車があります。Does that sound incorrect to you ?

Comment: No, but が doesn't go well with どこに.

Comment: @aguijonazo Interesting , thank you.

Comment: When you ask the location of something, you would expect the other person to know what you are asking the location of. You put it forward as a common topic between you two. Hence は. On the other hand, in a statement like 車があります, the existence of a car itself is new information. You need to tell what exists and this (車) cannot be a common topic at the time of utterance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it is important to note that the kanji of どこ is rarely used, and same for ある. In addition, in your question, you wrote `有る` which is the incorrect kanji for this usage of ある (有る represents possession; 在る represents location).

To answer your question, they are basically interchangeable, however `○○はどこにありますか` is a more polite way of saying `○○はどこですか`, so which one you use depends on the person with whom you're speaking.

Comment: "however of course it is not wrong to write them so" - I was under the impression that the correct kanji for the "location" ある would be 在る, while 有る is used for "possession" ある. I feel like the sentence structure in the question would not be about "possession" ある.

Comment: @Leebo Ah shoot, you're right - I'll edit my answer. 有る in this context is in fact incorrect; my brain just skimmed over it